# Why is casting to a type in this way not valid syntax?

Tags: c#

The compiler complains on "as typeOfState" saying that typeOfState could not be found. Why is this? Is there a way to express what I am trying to accomplish?

```
public static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> StateDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting>), "TabStates"},
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting>), "PaneStates"},
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadDockSetting>), "DockStates"},
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadDockZoneSetting>), "DockZoneStates"},
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadSplitterSetting>), "SplitterStates"},
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadSplitBarSetting>), "SplitBarStates"},
    {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting>), "RadPageViewStates"},
    {typeof(GlobalSettings), "GlobalSettings"},
};

foreach (var item in StateManager.StateDictionary)
{
    string stateName = item.Value;
    Type typeOfState = item.Key;

    object stateSession = SessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(stateName) as typeOfState;

    dataToSave.Add(stateName, stateSession);
}
```

Cheers

EDIT: Okay. Understood that cannot use a variable as a type, even if the variable is of type "Type"

What are my options? Here's full source:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Export()
{
    bool successful = false;

    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        SerializableDictionary<string, object> dataToSave = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var item in StateManager.StateDictionary)
        {
            string stateName = item.Value;
            Type typeOfState = item.Key;

            object stateSession = SessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(stateName);

            dataToSave.Add(stateName, stateSession);
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSave.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, dataToSave);

        successful = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.ErrorFormat("Unable to serialize session. Reason: {0}", exception.Message);
    }

    return successful;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `Type` object with the `as` keyword. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) for its proper usage.

To accomplish what I think you're trying to do, perhaps look into `Convert.ChangeType` *<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)]</sup>*.

Comment: Any suggestions on achieving the same functionality?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but now that I see more of the code, I don't think you need to do any conversion at all. Whenever the objects are serialized, the appropriate method will be called on the run-time type. Try it and see if that's not the case.

Comment: The issue arose in the fact that this SerializableDictionary seems to fail on empty collections. Was trying to check the collection size before adding to dataToSave.

Comment: And now I can tell that's not why it was failing.. so indeed, the conversion isn't necessary. :)

Comment: This answer would be improved if it stated what as could be used with rather than a single example of something that it can't be used with.

Comment: @David Heffernan Sure. I provided a link the the `as` keyword document.

Answer (score 2):

`typeOfState` is an object of type `Type`, it is not a Type. If you want to do what you are trying, you need to use Generics in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Because typeOfState is  a variable rather than a type. The as operator must be passed a type that is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `expr as T`, where `T` refers *to the name of a reference-type* (e.g. classname). `T` is not a general expression -- that is, it cannot be a variable name or a value representing a type (even if it is a `Type` object).

The compiler error message should indicate about as such.

Happy coding.